# Dash app: To develop a method that runs every time someone opens the app

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

I'm creating a dash web-app and need to develop a method to create a new dataframe for plotting every time someone opens this web-app
below are the sample code that I'm using.

```
def plot():
    dataframe = get_new_data_frame()
    fig = px.bar(dataframe, x='date', y='count')
    return fig
app.layout = html.Div(children=[
    html.H1(children='New DataFrame and Plot Every Time'),
   dcc.Graph(id='example-graph',
             figure = plot())
])
```

Here I want to develop a function get_new_data_frame() which return a newly created dataframe every time someone opens this web app. How can I do this ?

Comment: what is wrong with your current script?

Comment: this script is generating new dataframe only when I'm running the script for the first time after that when I'm opening the app again it is still using the previously generated dataframe but I want new dataframe each time some one opens the app

Comment: You can make a callback that is triggered every time a webpage is loaded, which then updates your dataframe (you can store the dataframe in a `dcc.Store`). the callback can be triggered by e.g. something like `Input('url', 'pathname')` if you want to load it every time you go to a specific page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by assigning a function to the layout of your app. Then inside this function create your dataframe and pass it to the layout

> By default, Dash apps store the app.layout in memory. This ensures that the layout is only computed once, when the app starts.
>
> If you set app.layout to a function, then you can serve a dynamic layout on every page load.

Dash provides the following example:

```
import datetime
from dash import html, Dash

app = Dash(__name__)

def serve_layout():
    return html.H1('The time is: ' + str(datetime.datetime.now()))

app.layout = serve_layout

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

https://dash.plotly.com/live-updates

---

Applied to your case it could look something like this:

```
def plot():
    dataframe = get_new_data_frame()
    fig = px.bar(dataframe, x="date", y="count")
    return fig


def serve_layout():
    return html.Div(
        children=[
            html.H1(children="New DataFrame and Plot Every Time"),
            dcc.Graph(id="example-graph", figure=plot()),
        ]
    )

app.layout = serve_layout
```